# Popup contact form

Tags: javascript, html, popup, contact-form

could you please help me find the problem in the below code?

When I open it in codepen it works. When I add it to my website, the JS is not working "$ is not defined". I'm a beginner so I don't know how to define $.

HTML is:

```
<div id="contact">Contact</div>

<div id="contactForm">

  <h1>Keep in touch!</h1>
  <small>I'll get back to you as quickly as possible</small>
  
  <form action="#">
    <input placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
    <input placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
    <textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    <input class="formBtn" type="submit" />
    <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#contact').click(function() {
      $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
      var container = $("#contactForm");
  
      if (!container.is(e.target) 
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
      {
          container.fadeOut();
      }
    });    
  });
```

Comment: $ is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Jquery without linking its CDN, adding this in your HTML head section should solve this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I've already corrected it, but thank you. 

And do you maybe know how to make the whole background of the website to grey/transparent grey or blurred with less opacity when the pupup is open?

Comment: Maybe this might help. Try setting the background color when the popup is selected. The alpha will make it blurry.

    #background{
         background-color: rgba(color1, color2, color3, alpha=0.5);
    }